# AMP Script - Populate last date of the third month in DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, date

set @todayUS = Now(1)
set @tomorrowUS = DateAdd(@todayUS, 1, "d")
set @yesterdayUS = DateAdd(@todayUS, -1, "d")
set @threeMonthsDate = dateadd(@today, 3, "M")
set @month = DatePart(@threeMonthsDate, "M")
set @year = DatePart(@threeMonthsDate, "Y")
set @firstOfThreeMonthsDate = dateparse(concat(@month,"-","01-", @year))
set @firstofThreeMonthsDate = FormatDate(@firstofThreeMonthsDate, "mm-dd-yyyy")
set @lastDaythirdMonth = dateadd(dateadd(@firstOfThreeMonthsDate,1,"M"),-1,"D")
set @lastDaythirdMonth = FormatDate(@lastDaythirdMonth, "mm-dd-yyyy")
set @todayUS = FormatDate(@todayUS,"mm-dd-yyyy")
set @tomorrowUS = FormatDate(@tomorrowUS, "mm-dd-yyyy")
set @yesterdayUS = FormatDate(@yesterdayUS,"mm-dd-yyyy")

Comment: Hi Apoorva. Welcome to SFSE. What have you tried so far, to solve this yourself? Did you search for the right Ampscript function to use?

Comment: Hey Lukas. Yes, I did try the code mentioned within my question description but no results.

Comment: When you write: ***It didn't work*** - what was wrong with the result?

Comment: I can see you at least are missing an "@" in your variable definition in your last line...

Comment: It didn't work = An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a ContentBlockByID function call. Function Call: ContentBlockbyID("64884") See inner exception for details.
An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a DatePart function call. See inner exception for details.
Invalid value specified for function parameter. Function Name: DatePart Parameter Name: Date Parameter Ordinal: 1 Parameter Type: Date Submitted Value: ClientID:

Comment: Apologies the missing @ was a copying mistake. The error I am getting now denotes an issue with the DatePart function call

Answer (score 2):

Ok I am updating my answer (overwriting it) as I ran your script and see the issues.

1. When you build the first day date, you are parsing it in dd-mm-yyyy format which means it is going to take the day (01) as the month and the month (02) as the day. This is because dateparse utilizings the mm-dd-yyyy format when parsing a date from a string.
2. your last day calculation is missing adding a month to the first day date, which means it is giving you just the day before the first, meaning it gives you the last date of the previous month to that.
3. your formatdate is formatting to the mm-dd-yyyy format when you said you want dd-mm-yyyy.
4. As @lukaslunow stated, youare missing the `@` in your variable call in the last line

See below for my adjusted code:

```ampscript
%%[
set @today = Now(1)
set @threeMonthsDate = dateadd(@today, 3, "M")
set @month = DatePart(@threeMonthsDate, "M")
set @year = DatePart(@threeMonthsDate, "Y")
set @firstOfThreeMonthsDate = dateparse(concat(@month,"-","01-", @year))
set @lastDaythirdMonth = dateadd(dateadd(@firstOfThreeMonthsDate,1,"M"),-1,"D")
set @firstofThreeMonthsDate = FormatDate(@firstofThreeMonthsDate, "dd-mm-yyyy")
set @lastDaythirdMonth = FormatDate(@lastDaythirdMonth, "dd-mm-yyyy")
]%%
%%=v(@threeMonthsDate)=%%<br>
%%=v(@firstOfThreeMonthsDate)=%%<br>
%%=v(@lastDaythirdMonth)=%%
```

Which outputs:

```
2/10/2023 8:31:22 AM
01-02-2023
28-02-2023
```

Comment: Hey Gortonington, thanks for sharing the solution. I am getting the error mentioned below. Earlier on when I tried on my own, it was the same error.  An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a ContentBlockByID function call. Function Call: ContentBlockbyID("64884") See inner exception for details below
An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a DatePart function call. See inner exception for details.
Invalid value specified for function parameter. Function Name: DatePart Parameter Name: Date Parameter Ordinal: 1 Parameter Type: Date Submitted Value: ClientID:

Comment: @Apoorva - I ran this through my enterprise and even MCSnippets (https://mcsnippets.herokuapp.com/s/CnKJ2Xex) to validate and it runs with no issues. The error may be coming from another part of your script - likely some sort of syntax error or missing parenthesis etc.

Comment: Hey Gortonington, I fixed it thanks. Just one last issue - the date I am getting is 01-02-2023 but it should be 28-02-2023 ( last day of the third month from today 11/11/22). Any clue why this must be happening?

Comment: I re-arranged the AMP a little and it worked. Thanks a million for your help on this.

Comment: Hi Gortonington, its me again. The code was working fine on Friday but today its throwing an error suddenly without any further updates. I am updating my question description with the code that I used for your reference. Have I written it incorrectly? Is the sequence of logic wrong? I am a novice sorry. The error is this = **An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a DateAdd function call. See inner exception for details.
Invalid value specified for function parameter. Function Name: DateAdd Parameter Name: InputDate Parameter Ordinal: 1 Parameter Type: Date Submitted Value: 14-11-2022**

Comment: @apoorva - you need to have it in YYYY-MM-DD format or MM-DD-YYYY format when using DatAdd, etc. as those functions will not accept DD-MM-YYYY or YYYY-DD-MM formats. It will try to read the DD as Months and if it is over 12, then it will error as there are only 12 months. Which is likely the issue you are facing. You can then reformat it to DD-MM-YYYY after the date math for display

Comment: Thanks G, that makes sense and it worked as well. But what if the date format was MM-DD-YYYY (for US based customers) Will that change anything in the code I have just updated in the questions description. Apologies for bugging I am very new to AMP Script and unfortunately there was no training at my new job. I tried updating the date format to MM-DD-YYYY based on the logic you shared for US customers but it's throwing the exact same error as the last time.